# ansible playbook / bash script

Tags: automation, ansible, production-environment

bonjour / hello

First of all sorry for my very poor english, I'm french and I used google translator.

I'm using an ansible playbook to run a bash script. In my test environment it works, but not in my production environment and I don't understand why.

It's a script that allows to scan for violations, check the status of the services and at the end it generates a report.

In ansible the task is accomplished but the report is not generated, whereas when I run the script directly from the terminal of my vm (hosted by aws) the script works and generates the report for me.

Can you help me please ?

```yaml
     - name: run the scan to generate deviation report
       become: yes
       command: sh /<path>
```

I tried several commands but I always have the same result. I tried the ansible script module and launched it in debug mode with `bash -x`

Comment: Bonjour et bienvenue sur SO. There's no way anyone can reproduce your problem with so little information. Please read [ask] and pay attention to the [mre] section. Then [edit] your question so that someone can actually try to help. Moreover, please do not use sentences as "It's (not) working" (at least used on their own) as [it does not accurately describe the problem you're facing](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Answer (score 0):

i tested like below

script:

```
root@swarm01:/myworkspace/ansible# cat hello.sh
#!/usr/bin/sh
touch abc
```

Playbook.

```
root@swarm01:/myworkspace/ansible# cat test.yml
- name: simple script
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: simple script
      command: sh hello.sh
```

```
root@swarm01:/myworkspace/ansible# ansible-playbook test.yml

PLAY [simple script] ***********************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [simple script] ***********************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

It worked for me, i see a abc file got created.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest using the [script module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/script_module.html)
This will allow the PB to run the script on remote systems as well as localhost.  Probably best to make sure you have the sh-bang on the first line of the script.

```
- name: simple script
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: simple script
      script:
        cmd: hello.sh
```